# javascript getting hour and min from epoch value

Tags: javascript, datetime

i am using the below code to get the hh:mm from epoch

```
 var dt = new Date(t*1000);  
    var hr = dt.getHours();
    var m = "0" + dt.getMinutes();
    return hr+ ':' + m.substr(-2)
```

for below values:

```
1542895249079  prints: 19:37  Expected: 2:00 PM
1542897015049  prints: 6:10  Expected: 2:30 PM
1542902445344  prints: 2:35  Expected: 4:00 PM
```

I am sort of lost on this as the conversion values from above code looks totally weird to me.

Comment: what is `t` here?

Comment: t is timestamp retrieved from server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems with your code:

1. For the example values you specified, there's no need to multiply by 1000 as they're already expressed in milliseconds.
2. If you want to leave local timezone information out of account, you have to use `getUTCHours()` and `getUTCMinutes()`.

```js
function convert(t) {
  const dt = new Date(t);
  const hr = dt.getUTCHours();
  const m = "0" + dt.getUTCMinutes();
  
  return hr + ':' + m.substr(-2)
}

console.log(convert(1542895249079));
console.log(convert(1542897015049));
console.log(convert(1542902445344));
```

Comment: Another issue was i was having t a string rather a number and i did the conversion and now it works good

Answer (score 3):

Not what you need, but someone is useful to get a really quick approximation.

I use to process large amounts of intervals. Conversions would be painful.

Example: The epoch time 1621271327 as Monday, 17 May 2021 17:08:47 GMT

```
1621271327 % 86400 / 3600 => 17.14 // hours
1621271327 % 3600 / 60 => 8.78 // minutes
1621271327 % 60 => 47 // seconds
```